# Can I enable antialiasing in the solid view during orbit / pan?

Tags: 3d-view, antialiasing

I seem to recall a setting that would enable anti-aliasing during viewport transforms in solid mode, but I can't for the life of me remember where this setting is or if it even exists. I think it was called something like "Fast Preview" or something similar.

I've installed a few different Blender builds and I'm concerned my preferences may have gotten corrupted and/or this setting was disabled inadvertently.

Here's a pic (this is during orbit):

[image]

Notice the jaggies on the bottom of the left chair.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can control the Viewport Antialiasing from Preferences > Viewport > Quality:

[image: AA]